# "She is pretty and beautiful" does this sentence sound natural?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

In Arabic, we have many similar adjectives that can be used together to describe a noun although they have similar meanings .
It is natural to say "This building is large and big" . Is it natural in English to say " She is pretty and beautiful "?

Comment: No, but you could say *She is pretty, even beautiful*. In this construction, using *even*, *beautiful* is a step up from *pretty*. Another example: *He was small, even tiny*. So, this construction is probably not equivalent in meaning to the Arabic one, but it is one in which the two adjectives can be used in one sentence separated by one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those particular pairs, no, that sounds unnatural. They are much too close and there is not that kind of habit in English in general.